# Android launcher changed

Tags: android

I have a Samsung GT-I900 (S1) and since two days my phone launcher changed suddenly in something that I can't get used.
After I made an upgrade to Android OS ver. 2.3.4 my first screen looks like that http://postimg.org/image/4og561mnz/ and after a few days, without doing nothing, the button of calls, messages and contact disappeared and looks like this http://postimg.org/image/cxkzp6wnf/

How can I change it back like was the first time and have the buttons of calls, messages and contact back?

Thanks for help!

Comment: can you drag and drop items to the launch pad?

Comment: You have acquired a rare minitablet that can accept calls but not send them. But seriously find the call icon in applications, press and hold it for 2 seconds, then drag and drop it back to where it was.

Comment: Looks like a question for http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about device usage and not programming. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing these steps should work:

- Tap `Applicati`
- Press the menu button
- Tap `Edit` (Or the equivalent    in your language)
- Swipe the screens until you find one of the apps    you want to have
  in the bottom area
- Tap and hold the icon
- Drop it in    the bottom area of the screen
- Proceed with all the apps you want to have in the bottom area.

Answer (score 0):

Go to All Applications, or Applicati in this case and just drag them from the Apps list to the bottom bar, that should work out!